# How to get url of background image of previous div while all div are dynamically changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am working on a web site in which i am using dynamic divs. My code is as follows:-

```
<div class="abc">
    <div clas="whole_0" style="background-image:url('demo0.jpg'); display:none;"></div>
    <div clas="whole_1" style="background-image:url('demo1.jpg'); display:none"></div>
    <div clas="whole_2" style="background-image:url('demo2.jpg');"></div>
</div>

<a href="#">Change-class</a>
<a href="#">get url of previous</a>
```

When i hover on 'change-class' than the class is changing dynamically.

All i want is that when i hover or click on it,the url of background image of previous div(running class is whole_2) i want whole_1's backround-image url....
Hope you get what i am saying....
Thanks in advance....

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get what you want (at all) :(

Comment: I am saying that i want the background-image:url('demo1') via javascript, Is there any way to get this in javascript....            i want 'demo1' as output...  Got it now???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem to get that.

I think that with `<div clas="whole..` you mean div `class="whole..` and it is just a typo

This is how: http://jsfiddle.net/RBQ8D/1/

```
$('.click').on('click',function(){
    $('.abc div').each(function(){
        if($(this).css("display")=="block") {
            alert($(this).prev().attr("style"));
        }
    });
});
```

**Update with background image only**
sorry @Zlatin Zlatev stole ir from you

http://jsfiddle.net/RBQ8D/2/

```
$('.click').on('click',function(){
    $('.abc div').each(function(){
        if($(this).css("display")=="block") {
            alert($(this).prev().css("background-image"));
        }
    });
});
```

now, depeding where your "active" picture is you could get trouble with the code snippet so you need to check if it is the first element or not. you can do that like this: http://jsfiddle.net/RBQ8D/3/

```
$('.click').on('click',function(){
    $('.abc div').each(function(e){
        if($(this).css("display")=="block" && e > 0) {
            alert($(this).prev().css("background-image"));
        } else if($(this).css("display")=="block" && e==0) {
            alert("next -->" +$(this).next().css("background-image"));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That returns the entire style, I think he just wants the URL.

Comment: Hey @caramba I expanded on your answer using some regex.

Comment: nice work @JayBlanchard, it looks like he also wants the "background-image" part, but I'm not sure, so actually I started answering just to give the OP an idea how to get it...

Comment: +1 for this....sir it worked like charm....@caramba

Answer (score 0):

You could use `jquery.css("background-image")` to get the background-image styling.
See http://api.jquery.com/css/

I would suggest that you use some kind of variable/attribute/class to store the current state and based on it to get the previous or next image from the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding @caramba's answer - If all you want is the text and not the path of the image's URL you'll have to use a little regex to get that -

```
$('.click').on('click', function () {
    $('.abc div').each(function () {
        if ($(this).css("display") == "block") {
            var imgURLString = $(this).prev().attr("style");
            console.log(imgURLString);
            var imgURL = imgURLString.match(/\'.*?\'/); // get everything in single quotes in the style declaration, returns an array
            console.log(imgURL[0]); // get the only item in that array, returns 'demo1.jpg'
        }
    });
});
```

So it depends on what you want. The regex can be modified to get things in parentheses or any other bracket.

http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/RBQ8D/4/

Comment: Very very thank you sir....for your help...@jay Blanchard